# android get data from server to client error

Tags: java, android

My application will connect to the server, and receive information about the server returns json format. But when I used httpclient and pick up information  returns a null value. please help me fix this.

Returns Information on server

```
{"token":"05940d1d5d764068816fdef1da1cc2e1","firstName":"Hà Duy","lastName":"Đinh","permission":["ADMIN_ORG","SHOOTING","MANAGE_IMAGE","PHOTOGRAPHER","IMAGE_PROCESSING","BUYER","PRODUCT_MANAGER","ADMIN_ORG","SHOOTING","MANAGE_IMAGE","PHOTOGRAPHER","IMAGE_PROCESSING","BUYER","PRODUCT_MANAGER"]}
```

My url

```
http://testing.lvsolution.vn:9876/cloudbizws/rest/auth/1039&haduy@lvsolution.vn&123456
```

My code

```
private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try
    {
    HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI website = new URI(url);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(website);
    response = Client.execute(request);
    }  catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: can you please add the logcat... and show us the `AsyncTask` how you are receiving the JSON

Comment: my code return reponse = null. no data, i can't parse json.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this code it will surely work

```
    String json = "";
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(uri));
        response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        json = reader.readLine();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: did you got exception ? put the debug pointer and trace the code where do you got error and check whether the exception is null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url); // or GET
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(post);
InputStream is  = resp.getEntity().getContent();            
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
 str.append(line + "\n");
```

}
   is.close();

To be sure the server send the response try to call the URL from the browser